# How can I add some single characters to my regex?

Tags: php, regex

I need have a validation function for characters `a-z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`.
However I need some more single characters to this. `Like ç, Ç, ş, Ş.`

```
protected function validate_alpha_dash($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match('/^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i', $value);
}
```

How should my pattern look like? I need to add like 10 more characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add them between the brackets, making sure the `-` stays at the end of the character class:

```
protected function validate_alpha_dash($attribute, $value)
{
    return preg_match('/^([a-z0-9_çÇşŞ-])+$/i', $value);
}
```

Comment: Careful with that `-`. Currently, you're getting a lot more than you bargained for...

Comment: If I only allow "ç", it passes anything after. (e.g other special characters too.)

Comment: @TimPietzcker; It's the builtin validation function of Laravel framework.

Comment: @Imaqtpie: That's because the character class allow all characters between `_` and `ç` to match. I was hoping Jerska would edit his/her answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks alot! The new solution worked flawlessly. I didn't knew it was this easy!

Comment: Oh one more thing, how can I allow space and dot characters? Worrying about space breaking regex and dot having a special meaning.

Comment: @lmaqtpie Yes you can, no worries, dot's special meaning is removed between brackets, and space is a character.

Comment: This is the final regex. /^([-a-z0-9_çÇğĞöÖşŞüÜıİ?!. -])+$/i Seems valid? Also, one last thing for you; how can I allow [tab] character?

Comment: Yes it does. Do it with its escaped sequence : "\t".